# Google oauth suddenly fails due to 503 when GAE tries to load https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth

The back-end for our Android game is implemented in GAE, it uses Google's oauth to authenticate our game users.

As of 2014-01-24 11:11:18.039 PST all the oauth requests began to fail. It looks like the requests from google oauth library to load the Google certs are failing:

Failed: Cause 7 (503) IOException Could not fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

However I can load that url manually in a browser no problem.

Our GAE uses Google's libraries e.g. google-oauth-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar etc

Any idea what is going on? This is breaking all back-end (user registration etc.) for our game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of Google Apps appear to be down right now, as per the [Apps Status Dashboard](http://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status&ts=1390590991290).

Though I don't see oauth specifically listed there, I think it is fairly safe to assume that this problem is related.

Comment: Ah, yup I expect you are right. At least our broken app has company

Comment: Yup, shortly after Google's other apps went back to fixed, oauth began to work again. Well, on the positive side we just did a worst-case stress test of our client recovery strategy when the server is down, and it passed with flying colors :) Other than setting up new accounts people were able to keep playing, and all the play results are catching up nicely. Next: burnt offerings to the god of idempotent server design!